# Placing a Chart using Apache POI ClientAnchor class

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi, anchor

I am writing a simple program to generate a Chart and place it in an appropriate place in an Excel sheet using POI version 3.17 and ooxml-schemas-1.3. The code for creating the anchor is:

```
    Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, [horizontalMove], 20, 8, 40);
    Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
```

It works perfectly if the value of horizontalMove (which is the column index) is between 1 and 10 but does not work for higher values i.e. horizontalMove = 55. Any workaround will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does "does not work" means? In [createAnchor(dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2, col1, row1, col2, row2)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Drawing.html#createAnchor-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-) the `col2` must be greater than the `col1` and difference `col2 - col1` is the width of the anchor in col widths. So if `col1` is set, `col2` should be set appropriate too.

Comment: Thanks Axel. Solved.